# Performing a long task in a handler

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to use aiojobs while using aiohttp to handle a long operation on a post endpoint. The process can take about 200 seconds on my local machine and when deployed to heroku the request will timeout after 30 seconds and also while this method runs it ties up my api for all other requests even while aiojobs is supposed to be handling the background task. Ideally I'd like to return a status pending message and a 200 status while in the background the task happens allowing all other traffic normally but I think I'm missing something.

```
 async def long_thing(request):
  try:
    body = await request.json()

    return web.json_response({"status": "success"}), await spawn(
        request,
        await long_stuff.really_long(body["field"]),
    )
    except Exception as e:

      return web.json_response(
          {"status": "failure", "error": str(e), "type": f"{type(e)}"}
      )


  app.add_routes(
  [
      web.post("/route", long_thing),
      #more routes here...
  ])


  app = web.run_app(app, port=os.getenv("PORT", 8080))

  setup(app)
```

Comment: You can't return 2 responses to a single request. Do you want a status pending and for it to run in the background or do you want the client to get the result?

Comment: I want it to start the job and return the response with a status of pending while the job's running in the background. In ruby on rails I would use something like sidekiq and redis for this but with the event loop I was hoping I was able to have multiple things happening at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In order to not be chopped out by the timeout, you can start your http response, then the provider will know your process did not "die", do your background processing, and stream the actual results later.

Although, keep in mind that Heroku may dcide to tiem out even if the response has started -

The way to do that is to [use aiohttp's `StreamResponse`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#streamresponse) instead of the regular `Response` used by json_response so that the headers are sent in advance. You will have to experiment with it, as you have to do the work that is automatically done by `json_response`: setting up the content_type header, and encoding the json body to bytes (`json.dumps(json_object).encode("utf-8")`) - besides using the StreamResponse instance correctly .

Now, even if you are streaming your response, it is up to heroku (and its terms of service) to kill or not your handler after the timeout. If starting an streaming resonse is not enough, you will have to use either web-sockets, or generate another callback URL for the front-end code to call poll after some time have ellapsed to check for your response. At this point you are in need for some careful design that goes beyond the scope of this answer.

For the second part of your question: how to avoid that the server stops handling anything else while processing one request: asyncio programs are actually single threaded - so, inside the code that takes time to execute in `long_stuff`, you have to yield the execution to the asyncio loop at regular intervals. This can be done by awaiting any call, and is usually done awaiting for a 0-second sleep - `await asyncio.sleep(0)`.

However, even if you do that, if you get 3 requests that would take each 200 seconds, the 3 together will take 600 seconds to complete. How to fix it depends on the nature of your long execution: if it makes I/O of any kind, you are likely using blocking I/O (i.e. not using "awaitable" calls to do the I/O) - find a way to do these in an async way and you are good. If, on the other hand, the 200 seconds are actually spent most in CPU time (some large data chunk being processed, or M.L. thing taking place), async alone can't help you: you have to paralelize that to another thread or process - check `asyncio.run_in_executor` for that. And if its actually CPU bond, this would at most defer your execution to another CPU core - which might not be available at all on your Heroku tier, meaning you will have to upgrade your plan to attend concurrent requests.